# How to parse a local xml file using dom in android?

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing

I have seen lots of examples about parsing local xml files with Sax but i need to do this with DOM. My xml file is under res/xml folder. Here is the code:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.maps);    



              StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

              DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance ();
              DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder ();
              Document document = db.parse(in, null);
              document.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
```

But it doesnt work. I think something missing with the line InputStream. It is really important for me, i need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Just need to change small thing:

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.bu);
```

I added "this" to that line and also I have put the maps.xml file under res/raw.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same. I was wondering why this openRawResource gets the XML file corrupted, and that's because it was placed in r.xml.* not in r.raw.*  :)

Comment: It is unclear from your answer if you are adding information or sharing your experience with the problem. Please edit the answer or convert to a comment.